# Install package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer for .net 4.5.2

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, .net-framework-version, package-manager-console

I'm trying to install the package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` but
in PMC I got the following error message:

> Install-Package : Could not install package
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.2.6'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain  any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author. At line:1
>   char:1
>   + Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

How can I install it for .NET Framework 4.5.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can't](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/platforms/).

Entity Framework Core 2.x only runs on .NET Standard 2.0, [meaning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) you need to target at least .NET Framework 4.6.1.